# Right Overflowed by 101 Pixels

Tags: flutter

Im very new at Flutter. I have developed app where Im trying to make improvements on it. Im Currently getting the error "Right Overflowed by 101 Pixels" when I want to add more text on a screen. I have done my research and come up with a solution but which is replacing the 'Row' to 'Wrap' but it doesn't quite work with the way I want it. When I replace the code to 'Wrap' it separets the green checkbox from the text. So I need to better solution. My code is;

```
  SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.check_box,
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                          Text('Unlock all exam questions'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.check_box,
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                          Text (
                              'Guaranteed to pass! We will refund you if you dont!'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 15.0, left: 20, right: 20),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          height: 60,
                          child: ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.green),
                              onPressed: () {
                                this._requestPurchase(_items[0]);
                              },
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text('Unlock Premium'),
                                  Text('£4.95'),
                                ],
                              )),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the Text widget with `Expanded` and for row alignment you may want `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,`

The structure will be like

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    Icon(
      Icons.check_box,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)